# Exception "value can not be null.Parameter name is value" occur while adding Play audio file to an existing outbound call using nexmo in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vonage

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MakeCall(string ToNumber)
    {
        string TO_NUMBER = ToNumber;  
        string NEXMO_NUMBER = "************"; 
        var results = Client.Call.Do(new Call.CallCommand
        {
            to = new[]
            {
                new Call.Endpoint {
                    type = "phone",
                    number = TO_NUMBER
                }
            },
            from = new Call.Endpoint
            {
                type = "phone",
                number = NEXMO_NUMBER
            },
            answer_url = new[]
            {
                "https://developer.nexmo.com/ncco/tts.json"
            },
            machine_detection = "hangup"
        });

        Session["UUID"] = results.uuid;
        return PlayAudioStreamToCall();
    }


    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult PlayAudioStreamToCall()
    {
        string NEXMO_CALL_UUID = Session["UUID"].ToString();
        var result = Client.Call.BeginStream(NEXMO_CALL_UUID, new Call.StreamCommand
        {
            stream_url = new[]
            {
                "https://nexmo-community.github.io/ncco-examples/assets/voice_api_audio_streaming.mp3"
            }
        });

        return RedirectToAction("MakeCall");
    }
```

context:
I have successfully done an outbound call but whenever I am trying to add "play an audio file" to an existing call, it gives me an exception of "value can not be null. Parameter name is value". Can somebody give me some suggestion?

Error Description:
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +242
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +66
Nexmo.Api.Voice.Call.BeginStream(String id, StreamCommand cmd, Credentials creds) +103

[Image Description:Error i got when i tried to add "play an audio file to an outbound call"
http://i66.tinypic.com/2wfoi0l.jpg  ].

[Image Description:UUID i got when i make an outbound call
http://i68.tinypic.com/mtqv7m.jpg  ]

Comment: you can always look at the changelog, so there is no "security" if you remove the phrase from the answer nor your question. Even if you delete your question, you will still be able to search it via web archive etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a Nexmo virtual number to make calls. 
When you sign up for a Nexmo account, you get some free credit so you can use that to get a number.

Comment: Thanku:)
can you recheck the post and give me some suggestion?

Comment: This is definitely not the reason for the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

To use TTS, you don't need to use BeginTalk, you just need to put the TTS in an NCCO and use it as the answer_url for the call.

Comment: https://github.com/nexmo-community/nexmo-dotnet-quickstart/blob/ASPNET/NexmoDotNetQuickStarts/Controllers/VoiceController.cs then why there is use of beginTalk while sending TTS

Comment: `BeginTalk` is used to interrupt an ongoing call with a new TTS instruction. If you don't need to interrupt an ongoing call, then just providing an NCCO with the `talk` command is simpler for reading text to the listener.

Comment: Judy2K Thanks for you advice :). If i am using BeginTalk, there should not be any problem also but my question is that why i am getting an error of " [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)" when i am trying to use BeginTalk or  BeginStream for TTS or Stream

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to send a voice call. In the end, creating a new application in Nexmo dashboard, and adding voice capability to this application seemed to solve the issue. I rechecked by removing the voice capability from the application and it gave me the Value cannot be null error. Hopefully this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

The poor error handling is a current issue in the SDK.

What happened is the response the SDK got back from the server wasn't successful so the SDK never extracted the JSON - so when it attempted to parse the JSON it kicked up this error.

It's impossible to say exactly what went wrong without the error code. I'd guess it was either a 401 (bad auth credentials) or a 400 (A mal-formed request).

Best bet is to enable logging, see the logging section of the [README](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-dotnet/blob/master/README.md) and see what error code you're getting back.